# Django subprocess

Tags: django, process, popen

I'm really sorry if this is a duplicate, but I have been searching, and haven't been able to find the answer.

In Django I want to do something like (see the comments):

```
# we have a file in our database...
v = create_file_entry(clean_data, ip_address)
# next, start a *background process* to upload the file somewhere else...    
p = Process(target=upload_file, args=(filepath,v))
p.start()
p.join()
# ...we don't care about the result of the process, or 
# wait for it to finish, just redirect the user to success *immediately*
return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
```

I want the code to start the upload_file process, and then redirect the user to the success page **immediately**, while the `upload_file` process runs in the background (it's slow). I thought a subprocess might do this.

Unfortunately the code above seems to wait for the `upload_file` process to finish before heading before redirecting the user to the success page, which is not what I need.

Note that `upload_file` is a Python function in my `views.py` file. I've heard about `popen` - I guess I could convert `def upload_file` into a  stand-alone Python script and run it from the command line - would that start running and then immediately redirect the user, as I want? Or should I be using some kind of thread/process?

**----UPDATE-----**

I think I might have figured it out... if I just do `p.start()` and NOT `p.join()`, then the process redirects immediately. Is there anything dangerous about this, though?

Answer (score 3):

Consider writing a separate daemon for the processing and communicating with it via a message queue.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't actually need to communicate with it, or know what the result is. I just need it to start. Surely there must be a simple way to do this?

Comment: ...by which I mean, start, and then let me redirect the user WITHOUT waiting for the result. Thread? Process? Popen? Help!

Comment: Put a message on the queue. The daemon then picks it up at its convenience and handles it.

Comment: You are communicating with the daemon by putting a message on the queue, there just will be no communication coming back from the daemon.  Think of the message that you put on the queue as your `p = Process(...)` line and the daemon grabbing the message and doing the work as your `p.start` line.