# Why do my subprocess calls require a page reload to execute?

Tags: python, django, firefox, subprocess

I have two separate `subprocess` calls in a django app, each in a different view. The first calls the dcraw image conversion tool to take an uploaded raw image and convert it into a tiff. (The .tiff output is usually nine times larger than the input, e.g. 8mb image yields 72mb tiff.)

```
pdcraw = subprocess.Popen(dcraw_args, stdout=None, stderr=None)
pdcraw.communicate()
```

My second subprocess calls a matlab script which processes the tiff and outputs relevant data files and images. This call usually takes a good 15-20 seconds when I run the script myself.

```
result = subprocess.Popen(matlab_args, stdout=None, stderr=None)
result.communicate()
```

My problem: with both of these subprocess calls, I have to reload the view manually for them to actually run. The rest of the code "around" them runs fine. Any thoughts on how I can avoid this? I'm wondering if it's some sort of cache issue, as I have been able to get the first subprocess to run a couple times before it starts requiring a reload. Your insight is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Things I've tried:

- Inserting `time.sleep` around the subprocesses, thinking maybe it's cut short. Doesn't work.
- Using pipes instead of `None` for `stdout`. I figure I should use `None` though, since I don't need to read the results from the command (they just output images to a directory specified in the args).
- Cursing at it. Still in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the whole idea of a subprocess is being asynchronous, it won't be ready when your view is parsed to the browser.

Perhaps you make an Ajax request to check the status of the progress, and as soon as files are available, they can then be send by the server.

Or you work with WebSockets, which can send any data as soon as it is available, omitting the need for extra requests while guaranteeing a superquick response.

Comment: Remi, he calls `communicate()` which actually waits for the process to terminate, so it is not really asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Remi. According to your explanation, wouldn't the subprocess still run even after the view is parsed? Theoretically my subprocess call creates a couple files; this doesn't happen at all unless I do the reload.

Comment: I found a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420471/django-subprocess). This guy instantiates a `Process` and uses `.join` generating the effect that `communicate` should do, with  success. On the other hand, sending a view directly and sending the results later is more pleasing than having to wait ... @Cianan, experiment also with the original `threading`, success is reported [here](http://www.artfulcode.net/articles/threading-django/#comment-2079)

Comment: I tried a quick implementation using Process - so far it exhibits the same behavior: on initial load neither command runs, but once I hit reload, both commands work. I'll look into the other thread next. Thanks for the leads!

Comment: @Remi I ended up using a modified form of the latter link you posted. And it works! Nice bonus that I got to learn all about queuing and threading. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! Why don't you post some small code as an answer to show your solution? I'll give it a +1!